# Where can I find javaee-5.jar source code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am doing JSF. I need to debug JSF source code. I am using javaee-5.jar. Where can I find javaee-5.jar source code? Thanks,

Comment: are you going to implement JEE spec? all of the servers has the javaee-5+.jar, if the IDE you are using not found the library, just add the server jee jar file but don't include it in the package

Answer (score 0):

I just want to find out the JSF implementation source code. Finally, I find it in oralce official site.

JSF implementation: https://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html

Answer (score 0):

You can download a decompiler: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/